# VBA to Create a folder based on the save path located in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the file save path located in J2, so I want to have a macro that creates a folder in the location that's in J2 and if that file is already created to end the process and loop to my other code which creates PDF's and save each one into that location. I already have that code working. I will paste both below:

This is the first code that I'm working on to create a folder based on the location in the cell

```
Sub MakeMyFolder()
Dim FldrName As String
On Error Resume Next
Set fsoFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fsoFSO.FolderExists = Range("J2") Then
    MsgBox "found it"
Else
    fsoFSO.CreateFolder = Range("J2")
    MsgBox "Done"
End If
End Sub
```

This is my second code that's already working that creates and saves PDF's in the location in J2

```
Sub PDF_Generator()

   Dim cell As Range
   Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
   Dim counter As Long

   Set wsSummary = Sheets("SUMMARY BY PROVIDER")

   For Each cell In Worksheets("NAME KEY").Range("$H2:$H60")
      If cell.Value <> "Exclude" Then

         'progress in status bar
         counter = counter + 1
         Application.StatusBar = "Processing file: " & counter & "/1042"

         With wsSummary
            .Range("$B$8").Value = cell.Value
            .ExportAsFixedFormat _
                  Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                  Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SUMMARY BY PROVIDER").Range("J2").Value & _
          "\" & cell.Value & ".pdf", _
                  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                  IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                  OpenAfterPublish:=False
         End With
      End If
Next cell

Set wsSummary = Nothing
End Sub
```

I want to get the first code working than combine that procedure with the next, any insight on this question will be great!

Comment: Using On Error Resume Next is almost NEVER advised.  You will not see errors that happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are functions so they have a return value. Try it like this:

```
fsoFSO.FolderExists(Range("J2"))
```

instead of

```
fsoFSO.FolderExists = Range("J2")
```

The same for `CreateFolder`:

```
Sub MakeMyFolder(strFolder as string)
    Set fsoFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fsoFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
        MsgBox "found it"
    Else
        fsoFSO.CreateFolder(strFolder)
        MsgBox "Done"
    End If
End Sub
```

To combine them, add an argument to your `sub MakeMyFolder(strFolder as string)`
I am assuming your cell that could have exclude will have the folder path, so call your sub with that as the argument; `MakeMyFolder cell.Value` from in your `PDF_generate` sub.

```
Sub MakeMyFolder(strFolder as string)
    Set fsoFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fsoFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
        MsgBox "found it"
    Else
        fsoFSO.CreateFolder(strFolder)
        MsgBox "Done"
    End If
End Sub

Sub PDF_Generator()

Dim cell As Range
Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
Dim counter As Long

Set wsSummary = Sheets("SUMMARY BY PROVIDER")

For Each cell In Worksheets("NAME KEY").Range("$H2:$H60")
  If cell.Value <> "Exclude" Then

     '******* Call your sub here with the folder to be creted ****************************
     MakeMyFolder cell.Value

     'progress in status bar
     counter = counter + 1
     Application.StatusBar = "Processing file: " & counter & "/1042"

     With wsSummary
        .Range("$B$8").Value = cell.Value
        .ExportAsFixedFormat _
              Type:=xlTypePDF, _
              Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SUMMARY BY PROVIDER").Range("J2").Value & _
      "\" & cell.Value & ".pdf", _
              Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
              IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
              IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
              OpenAfterPublish:=False
     End With
  End If
Next cell

Set wsSummary = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that do the trick, anyway on I how I can loop both macros and make it one macro function?

Comment: I get Argument is not optional, At the line where you put 'Call your sub here with the *****  I put Call MakeMyFolder

Comment: The next line calls it.  MakeMyFolder cell.Value  I am assuming cell.Value holds the folder you want to create. You need to pass the argument to MakeMyFolder. Just put the folder name after it.  From your code i don't know where you are getting the folder to be created.

Comment: Does J hold the folder value for each row?

Comment: Got you so I made the correction but it's doing the makemyfolder command for each pdf it's generating in my dropdown how to alter it to get to the point where the folder is created it doesn't have to run the command over and over or stop with the msg box pop up of "Found It"?

Comment: It depends on the larger scope of what you want. If you want it just to create the folder once, move it above the For Each loop.

Comment: Perfect moved it above the loop.  You rock thanks so much!